# Split strings at specified character in SQL

Tags: sql, string, split

I need to split a string in SQL at a specified character. I need to split TEX_TEXT field at the '(' character. I use it this way, but in the result the '(' is there.

```
Left(TEX_TEXT, CHARINDEX('(', TEX_TEXT ) ) as GroupName,
```

[image]

I need the result without the '(' charcter,  like this: 80, 80 Avant and so on.... Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about doing `... - 1`, or possibly even `... - 2` ?

Comment: What adjustment do you need to make to the second parameter of `left` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this demo. Using IIF, LEFT and CHARINDEX

```
declare @mytable table (col1 varchar(20))

insert into @mytable
values ('80 (xxx 123)'),('79'),('100 Avant (d1)')


SELECT
  LEFT(col1,        
             iif(
              CHARINDEX('(', col1) -- get location of 'C'
                  = 0,       -- if charindex is 0 then get length of the string
                    LEN(col1), -- thus this, if you don't check for no '(' then using charindex will return an error
                 CHARINDEX('(', col1) - 1) -- otherwise get the location of '(' minus 1
       )
FROM @mytable
```

result

```
80 
79
100 Avant
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is wrap it in a REPLACE() function. As you are splitting and taking the first part you can be sure there will only ever be one occurrence of the opening parenthesis.

```
REPLACE(Left(TEX_TEXT, CHARINDEX('(', TEX_TEXT ) ), '(', '') as GroupName
```

Last thing to do is RTRIM the whole lot to ensure there are no trailing spaces.

The best part to this approach is that you don't need to test the data before applying logic so it should work quicker than using an IIf statement